# Simple date picker always visible, no text box, required to checkout, some dates blocked

Tags: jquery, datepicker

The title summarizes it well, but I have been at this a while and tried a lot.  Trying to create a simple date picker for a shopping cart that is always visible(not just on click), doesn't have a text box(which seems to let people type in whatever they want), is required to move forward with checkout, and has some dates we select blocked.(not delivering things on holidays or our family's birthdays.

Here is what we have ( though new here and this doesn't appear to be running the same way as it is on our site https://shop.terrareef.com/cart ):

```js
var days = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"];
var unavailableDates = ["2020/12/1","2020/11/25","2020/11/26","2020/11/27","2020/12/11","2020/12/12","2020/12/24","2020/12/25","2020/12/26","2020/12/27","2020/12/31","2021/1/1"]; // yyyy/MM/dd
var unavailableDays = ["Saturday","Monday","Friday","Sunday"];

function unavailable(date) {
    ymd = date.getFullYear() + "/" + ("0"+(date.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + "/" + ("0"+date.getDate()).slice(-2);
    day = new Date(ymd).getDay();
    if ($.inArray(ymd, unavailableDates) < 0 && $.inArray(days[day], unavailableDays) < 0) {
        return [true, "enabled", "Book Now"];
    } else {
        return [false,"disabled","Booked Out"];
    }
}

  $(document).ready( function() {
    $(function() {
      $("#date").datepicker( {
        inline: true,
        minDate: '+2',
        maxDate: '+18',
        keepOpen: true,
        debug:true,
        beforeShowDay: unavailable
      } );
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
{{ '//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css' | stylesheet_tag }}
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js" defer="defer"> 
 </script>

<div style="float:right; width:300px; clear:both;">
  <p>
    <label for="date">Pick a delivery date:</label>
    <input id="date" type="text" name="attributes[date]" value="{{ cart.attributes.date }}" required autofocus/>
    <span style="display:block" class="instructions"> We currently ship corals Monday - Wednesday overnight. Delivery day assumes no carrier delays. Order will not ship if a date is not selected. Minimum order is $20.00</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

- Initiate the `.datePicker()` on a **DIV** element `<div id="dateDiv"` to make it always visible
- Use a **hidden** `<input hidden id="dateInput"` to store your submittable data
- Use `altField: '#dateInput'`,

```js
const days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];

const unavailable = {
  dates: ["2020/12/1", "2020/11/25", "2020/11/26", "2020/11/27", "2020/12/11", "2020/12/12", "2020/12/24", "2020/12/25", "2020/12/26", "2020/12/27", "2020/12/31", "2021/1/1"],
  days: ["Saturday", "Monday", "Friday", "Sunday"],
};

$("#dateDiv").datepicker({
  inline: true,
  altField: '#dateInput',
  minDate: '+2',
  maxDate: '+18',
  beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    const ymd = date.getFullYear() + "/" + ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "/" + ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
    const day = date.getDay();
    if ($.inArray(ymd, unavailable.dates) < 0 && $.inArray(days[day], unavailable.days) < 0) {
      return [true, "enabled", "Book Now"];
    } else {
      return [false, "disabled", "Booked Out"];
    }
  },
  onSelect: function(dateText) {
    $('#dateInput').val(dateText);
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<div>
  <label for="date">Pick a delivery date:</label>
  <input hidden id="dateInput" type="text" name="attributes[date]" required autofocus/>
  <div id="dateDiv"></div>
  <span class="instructions">We currently ship corals Monday...</span>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Test without the `hidden` property. Hope this should give you some ideas.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I like that approach, I love what I see when I run your snippet, but for whatever reason it will not run on my site.  Both the text box and the calendar are no longer visible:  https://9zg4h0idcu1b73k1-28956655715.shopifypreview.com

Comment: @Jon the error is right there staring at you :) *"`.datepicker()` is not a function"*. That means that you're trying to use a non existent method on the jQuery Object wrapper `$()` - most likely because you did not inserted the jQuery UI extension library with it's `.datepicker` method correctly.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I see this when inspecting.  Should this be loaded in the bottom of the header of theme.js ?  I see where support had commented some css and scripts there which I believe I loaded for this.  Sorry I learned some of this over a decade ago, but I'm lost.  I tried both pulling what I had out of comments and then also running the last two lines (scripts) you put above in the answer above, but no luck.

Comment: Sorry I am a bit lost.  I am willing to pay if you can help me get this finished.

Comment: @Jon the issue is pretty simple. Inspect your HEAD element. First you call your theme.js and only afterwards you call jQuery-UI. Your theme.js should go last, otherwise it'll be using some functions (like `datepicker`) that at that point in time were not existent. The order should be: 1. jquery 2. jquery-ui 3. your scripts that use jquery or jquery-ui. Also, in general, don't place `<script>` tags inside the HEAD - scripts are best placed always right before the closing `</body>` tag. That way you're always sure the the DOM is read and ready.

Comment: Thank you again.  I am sorry.  I am in an unfamiliar world.   I put the following in the header just below Google Analytics and well above the script that calls theme.js (which was part of the stores code before I started playing with things)
    {{ '//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js' | script_tag }}
    {{ '//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css' | stylesheet_tag }}  

It just isn't working.

Comment: I was originally following this help page:  https://shopify.dev/tutorials/customize-theme-add-date-picker-for-delivery-dates which said to "On a new line above the closing </head> tag, paste the following code", which is of course below the call for theme.js and then support commented out the jquery.min.js entirely.

Comment: @Jon also please note that you forgot that `jquery-ui.css` **is NOT** a javascript file. To repeat: jQ-ui.css goes in head. That's a stylesheet file, not a **script** file. So, styles go in `<head>`, `<script>` go right before the closing `</body>`. Don't know any more how to better explain. jQ-UI.css >>> inside `<head>` ... jQ.js, jQ-ui.js, theme.js >>> before `</body>`

Comment: @Jon to recap: `<link>` elements go in `<head>`. Order matters. `<script>` tags go before the closing `</body>` Order matters. A `.css` file does not contains JavaScript methods like `.datepicker()` - it contains the datepicker styles, not the scripts.

Comment: The current shop cart we have here https://shop.terrareef.com/cart   functionally works as far as a calendar coming up if you click on the text, "Pick a delivery date:"  and if someone selects a date it shows up when they check out.  The issue with it is they can type anything they want and it is messy when void on an android device with the calendar getting hidden behind the keyboard.  I guess jquery loads somehow correctly on that though I see it commented out in the header.  If I copy that entire theme and past your code in delivery-date.liquid and them.js everything disappears from cart.

Comment: https://1vweb7derk0114ds-28956655715.shopifypreview.com

Comment: Going crazy, I have to step away for a little bit.